# Ajax request with a response from a different Django View

Tags: django, ajax

I am trying to get my head around executing the following idea using Django and Ajax. I already understand how to implement the validation email side of things and the JQuery required to change button colors etc. My question solely relates to how I should set up the Ajax interaction between two different views.

What I would like to be able to do is;
A 'validate email' button is clicked on a webpage and a request is sent via Ajax to a Django view (validate_view()) - the button changes colour to Orange.  Then, validate_view() sends an email with an activation link back to the Django server and activate_view() captures the uidb64 and token and updates the database, job done.

My question is, how do I then send a response back to the page? (primarily to change the original button colour to Green)

Comment: Please update your question with code that you have done so far

Comment: you can do it using the good old style by doing an ajax request every 30 seconds for example to check if email is verified, if yes, then turn the button back to green. 
Or
You can setup websocket to listen to updates being pushed to user.  If all you need is a `is_email_verified` then it's easier to go with the first option.

Comment: Thanks Ramy. I might be wrong,  but the Ajax request every 30 seconds would trigger a server side trip to the database each time which is something that I wish to avoid. However the web sockets idea is interesting - thank you.